# EFI shell no filesystem detected

Tags: debian, shell, efi

I'm tinkering with EFI Shell in VirtualBox. I've got a guest OS installed on a raw partition with a bootloader in it. The problem is I can't find a way to mount the desired partition so that I can at least search through the files in it and boot manually;

```
Shell> map
    Mapping table
        BLK0: Alias(s):
        ...
        BLK7: Alias(s):
Shell> fs0:
    'fs0' is not a valid mapping.
Shell> blk0:
Shell>
```

As you can see, it just doesn't work like I expected. How can I find and mount my filesystem from inside this shell?

Comment: Is the partition you're trying to mount FAT32? _(While EFI boot does support other filesystems, such as NTFS, support for anything other than FAT32 must be built into the EFI firmware itself by the motherboard manufacturer.)_

Comment: Hmm, it can actually be ext4. I'll look into that